# Running tigris package from terminal

Tags: r, tigris

I posted this question the other week but it didn't get any response, hope it's okay to post again. Here's some code:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla

library(tigris)
shp <- tracts(state = 'New York', county = 'New York')
print(shp)
```

I can run this code from the console perfectly, but when I try to run it from terminal (osx 10.10.5) I get the empty SpatialPolygons object seen here:

[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong? This seems like super basic but I can't figure it out - thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Totally reproducible. I'll add this as an issue to the project.

Comment: Added it https://github.com/walkerke/tigris/issues/18

Comment: Use the latest dev version from here - https://github.com/hrbrmstr/tigris - until it's on CRAN. Found the bug that was causing the weird behavior in non-interactive mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for finding the bug!  The dev version should work for you (I've tested it locally on Windows) and the updated version has been submitted to CRAN.

**Update: the new version is now on CRAN.**